# Fitting Pickerview and Tableview as subviews on the same screen

Tags: iphone

I want to find the best way to fit both a UIPickerview and a UITableview on the same screen (View). I can't find a way to size them in IP or dynamically resize them. I want to keep their font sizes small to balance it all and fit a Tab Bar at the foot of the screen.

I'll be using one Controller for both of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at a UITableView in Interface Builder, you can't resize the view itself and have an empty space at the bottom.  If you just have a UIView with a UITableView and a UIPickerView as two subviews, resiszing the UITableView should be trivial and obvious.